# Prevent to read file multiple times from dynamic fileInput

Tags: r, file-io, shiny, lapply, observers

I've created a dynamic fileInput in shiny using lapply. When I want to read the file, I've also used lapply in an observer.

The problem of using lapply here is, it is triggered every time I upload a new file and thus, reads all files again and again if a new file is uploaded.

Here I provide a Hello World app. The lapply function depends on an input paramter which I abtracted from for simplicity.

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello World"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            lapply(1:2, function(i) {
                fileInput(
                    paste0("file", i),
                    label = NULL,
                    multiple = F,
                    accept = c(
                        "text/csv",
                        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                        ".csv"
                    ),
                    buttonLabel = paste("File", i)
                )
            }),
            verbatimTextOutput("list")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    r <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
        lapply(1:2, function(i) {
            file <- input[[paste0("file",i)]]
            if(is.null(file)) return()
            isolate({
                r$file[[paste(i)]] <- readr::read_csv2(file = file$datapath)
            })
        })
    })
    output$list <- renderPrint(reactiveValuesToList(r))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How to replace the loop or add a requirement to lapply?

Comment: The code example is perhaps a little too small: an `observe` that just reads data (and immediately discards it) doesn't show what you are trying to do. But a thought: is it possible that a file will be re-uploaded with the same name but different data? If yes, then you have a problem of *cache-invalidation*: you can choose to not re-read files you've seen previously, but if a new (different data) file is uploaded with the same name, you'll never see it.

Comment: If you are certain that same-name will always be the same (or willing to accept the consequence), then I suggest you create a `rv <- reactiveValues()` with names being file names; in your `observe`, check to see if a filename is already read (`file$datapath %in% names(rv)` for each file), and if not store the table (`rv[[ file$datapath ]] <- readr::read_csv2(...)`).

Comment: I think you can ignore the comments above ... on further reading, it is not (necessarily) about cache-invalidation so much as controlling reactivity amidst dynamically-created reactive blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Data is not directly discarded in my app. I added reactiveValues to the file section and an output to indicate a processing and saving scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I started down the road of *cache-invalidation* in the comments, I think something else may work better for you since you have a fixed number of `fileInput` fields: swap the `lapply` and `observe` lines in your code (plus a couple of other tweaks).

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  lapply(paste0("file", 1:2), function(nm) {
    observeEvent(input[[ nm ]], {
      req(input[[nm]], file.exists(input[[nm]]$datapath))
      readr::read_csv2(file = input[[nm]]$datapath)
    })
  })
}
```

Explanation:

- I'm creating a list of reactive blocks instead of a reactive block operating on a list. This means `"file1"` won't react to `"file2"`.
- I short-cutted the definition of the input names by putting `paste0(...)` in the data of the `lapply` instead of in the function, though it'd be just as easy to do

  ```r
  lapply(1:2, function(i) {
    nm <- paste0("file", i)
    # ...
  })
  ```
- It's important to have `nm` defined *outside* of the `observeEvent`, and it has to do with delayed evaluation and namespace search order. I fell prey to this a few years ago and was straightened out by Joe Cheng: you can't use a `for` loop, it must be some environment-preserving operation like this.

N.B.: this is a stub of code, and it is far from complete: having an `observe` or `observeEvent` read the data and then discard it is wrong ... it's missing something. Ideally, this should really be a `reactive` or `eventReactive` block, or the processed data should be stored in a `reactiveValues` or `reactiveVal`. For example:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- lapply(paste0("file", 1:2), function(nm) {
    observeEvent(input[[ nm ]], {
      req(input[[nm]], file.exists(input[[nm]]$datapath))
      readr::read_csv2(file = input[[nm]]$datapath)
    })
  })
  observe({
    # the following are identical, the latter more declarative
    mydata[[1]]
    mydata[["file1"]]
  })
}
```

(And another note about defensive programming: you cannot control perfectly how `readr::read_csv2` reacts to that file ... it may error out for some reason. One further step would be to wrap it in `tryCatch(..., error = function(e) { errfun(e); NULL; })` where `errfun(e)` does something *meaningful* with the error message (logs it and/or gives it to the user in a modal popup) and then returns `NULL` so that reactive blocks downstream can use `req(mydata[[1]])` and will not try to process the `NULL`.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- lapply(paste0("file", 1:2), function(nm) {
    observeEvent(input[[ nm ]], {
      req(input[[nm]])
      file <- input[[nm]]
      tryCatch(
        readr::read_csv2(file = input[[nm]]$datapath),
        error = function(e) { errfun(e); NULL; })
    })
  })
  observe({
    # the following are identical, the latter more declarative
    mydata[[1]]
    mydata[["file1"]]
  })
}
```

Comment: The lapply part works great now, thanks, one file does not depend on the next. Though sorry if I missed a part, but saving lapply crashed my app `Error in <observer>: attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I typed without testing. `reactiveVal` requires the parens, `reactiveValues` does not. I'm removing it from my answer.